# Subdominio dinamico com htaccess e php

Tags: php, htaccess, dns, cpanel, wildcard

Estou quebrando a cabeça. Preciso criar subdominios dinamicos para cada usuario que se cadastrar em meu site (ex.: usuario1.dominio.com.br, usuario2.dominio.com.br, usuario3.dominio.com.br) sem precisar criar um a um no cpanel.

Sei que isso tem haver com wildcard criei a entrada dns *.meudominio.com.br mas não funciona.

Quero fazer como neste exemplo: http://thewallchat.com/

Tentei este tutorial: https://www.9lessons.info/2016/03/how-to-create-dynamic-subdomains-using-php-and-htaccess.html mas não deu certo pois no cpanel não deixa criar entrada de dns com @.

quem puder me ajudar fico agradecio.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, isso é bem simples, usando wildcard *, veja se pode ajudar:

https://brasilwork.com.br/tutoriais/como-criar-um-subdominio-wildcard-curinga-cpanel/

Comment: Felipe, acredito que o que ele quer é algo dinâmico do tipo: um usuário se cadastrou no site... logo ele terá um subdomínio... `felipe.dominio.com.br`. Pelo menos foi o que eu entendi.

Comment: Inclusive ele colocou o link do exemplo: http://andrei.thewallchat.com/

Comment: Isso mesmo, neste tutorial explica exatamente como fazer isso no cPanel... em seguda ele podera acessar qualquer sub domínio dinâmico (ex: teste1.thewallchat.com ou teste11111.thewallchat.com... etc)

Comment: Legal Felipe! Não tinha entendido o tutorial. Esperava algo com .htaccess. =)

Comment: Valeu Felipe consegui fazer, agora como faço para cada usuário ter uma pasta? Por exemplo, o usuário Felipe tem uma pasta com este nome no meu servidor e ao acessar felipe.dominio.com.br os arquivos da pasta deste usuário são carregados como se fossem a pasta raiz do servidor.

Pra ser mais objetivo o que eu quero é criar uma aplicação multi-tenant mas sem laravel nem framework nenhum, pode parecer uma coisa idiota mas gostaria muito que isso fosse possível.

Comment: Bem, eu iria fazer algo no PHP ex:
<?php
$dominio = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($dominio = 'felipe.dominio.com.br'){
 include('/pasta/do/felipe.dominio.com.br');
}
if($dominio = 'teste.dominio.com.br'){
 include('/pasta/do/teste.dominio.com.br');
}
?>

Você pega o domínio atual no PHP depois trabalha nele o que deseja exibir conforme o domínio, também pode obter isso do banco mysql!